# Rotate tls secret - Ingress - kubernetes

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-secrets

I need to update my tls secrets, there is any best practices to do that?,

The steps considered by now are:

- Create new secrets
- Update the ingress definition in order it could take the new tls secrets.

I can´t use cert-manager with letsencript.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to update my tls secrets, there is any best practices to do
> that?, by now, I think, I have to create new secrets and update my
> ingress definition in order it could take the new tls secrets.

Yes you are right Or else you can update the existing secret directly and no changes will be required to do the ingress side.

Create the YAML file with same name of secret and changes will get over write.